# Open source image skew detection/correction libraries in java?

Tags: java, image-processing, skew

I need to perform skew correction on some images (lets say the format is tiff). That is, I have some images which can come in tilted to the right or left and I need to adjust them so that they are straight up and down. The images consist of text and lines; the lines are basically borders around the text; so all of the lines are horizontal and vertical (which hopefully simplifies the problem).

Is there an open source java library that would help with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect (and correct) skew in images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170501/how-can-i-detect-and-correct-skew-in-images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have searched a little better. Answer is here:
[How can I detect (and correct) skew in images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170501/how-can-i-detect-and-correct-skew-in-images)

And a nice open source library is here:
http://www.jdeskew.com/

Comment: Linke is broken